# Error in changing element of list of lists in python

Tags: python, list

I created list of lists in python by 3 methods. When I changed any element of list, All corresponding elements of each row were changed by using method 1 and 2 for list creation. What is actually happening in method 1 and 2?

method 1:

```
>>> a = [['_']*3]*3
>>> a
[['_', '_', '_'], ['_', '_', '_'], ['_', '_', '_']]
>>> a[1][1] = 1
>>> a
[['_', 1, '_'], ['_', 1, '_'], ['_', 1, '_']]
```

method 2:

```
>>> row = ['_']*3   
>>> board = []
>>> for i in range (3):
...     board.append(row)
... 
>>> board
[['_', '_', '_'], ['_', '_', '_'], ['_', '_', '_']]
>>> board[1][1] = 1
>>> board
[['_', 1, '_'], ['_', 1, '_'], ['_', 1, '_']]
```

while doing with list comprehension works:

```
>>> arr = [['_' for i in range(3)] for i in range(3)]
>>> arr
[['_', '_', '_'], ['_', '_', '_'], ['_', '_', '_']]
>>> arr[1][1] = 1
>>> arr
[['_', '_', '_'], ['_', 1, '_'], ['_', '_', '_']]
>>>
```

Comment: When you create lists with `*`, the returned lists refer to the same object, whereas they are created independently in your list comprehension. You can verify this with `a[0] is a[1]` and `arr[0] is arr[1]`

Answer (score 0):

When you use solution 1 and 2, you actually create 3 pointers to the same list. This is equivalent to:

```
a = ['_']
b = a
```

If you modify a or b, the result will be the same.